# Is it possible to restrict the usage of service provided by a module in JPMS?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

Let's suppose we have JPMS modules - `A`,`B`, `C` etc. `A` defines some service `a.spi.SomeService` and all there modules have implementation of this service. For example, module `B` has an implementation of this service `b.spi.SomeServiceImpl`, so, in module-info of `B` we have:

```
provides a.spi.SomeService with b.spi.SomeServiceImpl;
```

Can we make the service of `A`, which provides module `B`, `C` etc available only to module `A`, so as all other modules, even if they provides `a.spi.SomeService` too, couldn't use it?

Comment: [Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7) confirms `provides TypeName with TypeName {, TypeName} ;`, you cannot expose it to a closed set of modules similar to exporting a package as in `exports PackageName [to ModuleName {, ModuleName}] ;`. So just and restrict that package of your provide to be exported/opened to a specific module, wouldn't that work? Or is it a cycle? Complete descriptors would help better analyse.

Comment: *Can we make the service, which provides module B available only to module A?* .. If you need the implementation provided by `B` in `A`. It would be a cyclic dependency in my opinion. What use case drives this? Why can't `A` have the implementation in itself and `export` it for `B` to re-use. Or else can your question be simplified to - "Is it possible to restrict the usage of service provided by a module."? Regarding the renaming, for the sake of the question, you can name it to `a.spi.SomeServiceProvider` and `b.SomeServiceProviderImpl` (but that's not important here imo.)

Comment: @Naman I have the following situation - one module has service interface and this module is the service consumer. All other modules provides this service. And I want that only module A could use provided services.

Answer (score 1):

You can export a package only to certain modules:

```
module A {
  exports a.spi to B
}
```

Comment: This solution is absolutely wrong. You allow access to `a.spi` only to one module - moudle B. The question is that N modules can implement the interface from module A, but only module A can use implemented services.